# Entity Framework 5 inheritance generating as TPT instead of TPH?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to implement various tables that inherent a groups table. When I generate the database from the model it comes out as type-per-table instead of type-per-inheritance like I would like.

I have:

1. Group set to abstract
2. Each group type table is mapped to Group conditionally when type(column) = a different int for each table

Can anyone point me in the right direction for what I need to do to change this to type per inheritance?

EDIT: by request via comment here is my db set for group, and none of the group types of a dbset

```
public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
```

Here are the generated classes:

Group:

```
public abstract partial class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        this.GroupHierarchies = new HashSet<GroupHierarchy>();
        this.GroupHierarchies1 = new HashSet<GroupHierarchy>();
        this.NetworkActions = new HashSet<NetworkAction>();
        this.PermissionAssignments = new HashSet<PermissionAssignment>();
        this.UserProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupHierarchy> GroupHierarchies { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupHierarchy> GroupHierarchies1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NetworkAction> NetworkActions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PermissionAssignment> PermissionAssignments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

One of the group types:

```
public partial class HoaManagementCompany : Group
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

The other group type, there will be many more in the future but only these two until I get it to work.

```
public partial class HoaAttorney : Group
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please, show your mappings

Comment: [This Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) has a pretty thorough example.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky My mappings are here http://imgur.com/isOyCA0,HA9hfIE,TkDd0iQ,6qaEWE4,aDBtxvd

Comment: Can you show the DBSets in the context

Comment: @kirsteng added the dbsets to the question. thanks for the help so far everyone

Comment: Also the POCO classes please.  I think there should only be one DBSet
 for TPH. This would be DbSet<Group> Groups { get;set;}

Answer (score 3):

> When I generate the database from the model...

Are you using Model-First strategy? This unfortunately would make it difficult to get TPH inheritance for your model (which would be easy for Code-First or Database-First strategy).

(Default inheritance mapping for Code-First is TPH, so you should not have your problem with Code-First.)

Out of the box TPH is not available with Model-First. The default inheritance strategy for Model-First is TPT and there is [no easy way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx) to switch to TPH in the model designer:

> It is possible to map to a TPH inheritance using Model First but you
>   would have to write your own database generation workflow which is
>   complex. You would then assign this workflow to the Database
>   Generation Workflow property in the EF Designer. An easier alternative
>   is to use Code First.

There is an additional tool from Microsoft - the [Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87) - which supports TPH database generation workflow for Model-First. But the problem is that it doesn't look very well maintained (last update from May 2012) and it doesn't support Visual Studio 2012. But if you use VS 2010 you can try it.

Comment: This is very disappointing to find out, but is the information I was looking for. Thanks you. Up-voted & will mark as answer at the end of the day to leave a little time for others to possibly provide other information.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use your Groups DBSet for TPH.
Also make sure you aren't adding Table annotations to the poco classes

Comment: I still cant seem to get this to work. I added the classes to my original question. Thank you for the help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this blog, it worked for me in the past.

[Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 1 – Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx).

Also talks about `Table per Type (TPT)` and `Table per Concrete class (TPC)` Inheritances.